# How do I return the end of a directory

Tags: c++, string, directory

I have a function that is supposed to find the last bit of a directory in a string. eg:
"C:\Lolcats\pie\ambulance\" should return "ambulance". However it returns some strange characters ive never seen, like the male arrow-point symbol and some other weird stuff.

```
string App::getlastName(string cakes){
    //finds the name of the last folder in a directory
    string name;
    string temp;//popback all of temp into name to invert it
    cakes.pop_back();
    char i = cakes[cakes.length()-1];
    while (i != '\\'){
        temp.push_back(cakes[i]);
        cakes.pop_back();
        i = cakes[cakes.length()-1];
    }                           //-1?
    for (int j = 0; j<temp.length(); ++j){
        name.push_back(temp.back());
        temp.pop_back();
    }
    return name;
}
```

This is probably one of the worst functions i've ever written, but I  can't think of how else to wrangle the end off :( Can someone help me please? :D

Note that the function doesnt need to find the name of a file, it'll just be folders.

Comment: Why not just use `basename`, either from the standard C library or from boost::filesystem ?

Comment: or a nice friendly regex? I mean, even a messy series of substr calls would be better than that.

Comment: `temp.push_back(cakes[i]);` is your big mistake. i is a character from your string, not an index into your string.

Comment: Gah how dumb of me! I'm just so used to i being an int in a for loop lol:/ thanks Joel :3
John i'll google regex. 
Paul i'm avoiding boost because I couldnt get it to work lol

Comment: If you're used to using i as an int in a for loop, use a different name in this case so you don't confuse yourself. (Although the right answer here is to follow one of the suggestions in the Answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the trailing \ off the string you can use a simple combination of rfind and substr to get the data you want.

```
string substring = cakes.substr(cakes.rfind("\\") + 1);
```

Comment: Beautiful :3 I used:

cakes = cakes.substr(cakes.rfind("\\") + 1);

After popping back the slash at the end. Cheers man :3

Answer (score 4):

Two steps:

- if it ends with a backslash character remove it:

  ```
  if (!cakes.empty() && '\\' == *(cakes.end() - 1))
  {
      cakes.erase(cakes.end() - 1);
  }
  ```
- use [`std::string::find_last_of()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of) to locate last backslash and [`std::string::substr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) to extract the last part:

  ```
  std::string last_part;
  const size_t slash_idx = cakes.find_last_of("\\");
  if (std::string::npos != slash_idx)
  {
      last_part = cakes.substr(slash_idx + 1);
  }
  ```

If it is possible that the directory name could contain forward slashes add the additional check for the last character and just add it to the argument to `find_last_of("\\/")`, as it can search for more than one character.

Answer (score 0):

Your method depends on the string already being in the correct format with no assertions or error checking--not a good idea.

I would just do something like:

```
char* directoryName = strrchr(fullPath, '\\') + 1;
```

after you have trimmed off the trailing '\'.

Comment: Don't worry about the string format, i've got that handled elsewhere :3

Answer (score 0):

@Joel Rondeau's comment where he says that the line `temp.push_back(cakes[i])` is a problem is correct, but I thought I would elaborate.

The reason is that the variable `i` is defined as a `char` not an `int`, but it is possible for the two to be cast implicitly. So the reason why you are getting strange characters returned is because casting a `char` to an `int` has resulted in an index value that probably does not exist in your string.

Reading your code sample it looks like you should be doing `temp.push_back(cakes[cakes.length()-1])` instead (or better, store this index in a temp variable so you don't have to keep writing it every time).